# Pacing Time and Iteration calculation

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, loadrunner

Below are the client requirement:
1.Transactions Per Hour(TPH)-50, 2.No.Of Users-5,  3.Test duration-1hour

How to calculate the iteration time and pacing time to acheive the 50TPH per Hour.

I have calculated using Littles law but TPH achieved is 80TPH per hour but requirement is 50TPH per hour.

Could any one please help me

Comment: You need a mentor if you are going to be asked to deliver services without training.  Your management owes you that.  Forums on the Internet are not a substitute for a mentor to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Given you have [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) tag you should not need to calculate anything, the desired number of request per unit of time can be obtained using the following test elements

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

---

If you still need the formula given your requirement of 50 TPH with 5 users:

1. 50 TPH means that each user needs to make 10 transactions per hour
2. 10 transactions per hour means that each user needs to make a transaction each 6 minutes

So if iteration time tool less than 6 minutes you need to wait the remaining time. If you're getting 80 transactions per hour it means that you simply don't wait long enough.